# Get solana NFT on-chain data using python

Tags: python, blockchain, solana

How can I get Solana NFT on-chain data (like the NFT creators) using python?

There is the solana-py lib, but I didn't find a relevant function for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not specialist in Blockchains/NTF/Web3 so I'm not sure if it is what you need.

If you create (free) account on [blockchainapi.com](https://dashboard.blockchainapi.com) (it needs Google Account) and get API keys then you can use even module `requests`.

```
import requests
import pprint

headers = {
    'APIKeyId': 'MY_API_KEY_ID',
    'APISecretKey': 'MY_API_SECRET_KEY',
}

network = 'mainnet-beta'
mint_address = '3LZ9ezL5BkCtvdVGLkrw1q633EgfeYDpgGtBgWDgmaSU'

# --- metadata ---

url = f"https://api.blockchainapi.com/v1/solana/nft/{network}/{mint_address}"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = response.json() 

pprint.pprint(data)

# --- owner ---

url = f"https://api.blockchainapi.com/v1/solana/nft/{network}/{mint_address}/owner"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = response.json() 

pprint.pprint(data)
```

Result:

```
{'data': {'creators': ['64eiSEPv2KRKNkPAX6d4BZQ3b12PcFqZP2yPoNAZw9po',
                       'yeT3ik5jX5RuK8JF8P3RRHrr9g6ox6RMWbRMh3r9FxQ'],
          'name': 'Baby Yetis #257',
          'seller_fee_basis_points': 500.0,
          'share': [100.0, 0.0],
          'symbol': '',
          'uri': 'https://arweave.net/4PtHGFuAw2U-T4nrIWVRxJ0EpVIivRWi4xjreBkmMVg',
          'verified': [0.0, 1.0]},
 'explorer_url': 'https://explorer.solana.com/address/3LZ9ezL5BkCtvdVGLkrw1q633EgfeYDpgGtBgWDgmaSU',
 'is_mutable': True,
 'mint': '3LZ9ezL5BkCtvdVGLkrw1q633EgfeYDpgGtBgWDgmaSU',
 'primary_sale_happened': False,
 'update_authority': 'yeT3ik5jX5RuK8JF8P3RRHrr9g6ox6RMWbRMh3r9FxQ'}

{'nft_owner': '8hJSGbZhk4q8LjeRRXaLfKEPhEHQLBpLPrd1mmAG4953'}
```

The same NFT on

- [explorer.solana.com](https://explorer.solana.com/address/3LZ9ezL5BkCtvdVGLkrw1q633EgfeYDpgGtBgWDgmaSU)
- [solanart.io](https://solanart.io/nft/3LZ9ezL5BkCtvdVGLkrw1q633EgfeYDpgGtBgWDgmaSU)

Doc blockchainapi: [solanaGetNFT](https://docs.blockchainapi.com/#operation/solanaGetNFT), [solanaGetNFTOwner](https://docs.blockchainapi.com/#operation/solanaGetNFTOwner)

---

**EDIT:**

There is also python module `theblockchainapi`

(`pip install theblockchainapi`)

```
from theblockchainapi import TheBlockchainAPIResource, SolanaNetwork
import pprint

BLOCKCHAIN_API_RESOURCE = TheBlockchainAPIResource(
    api_key_id='MY_API_KEY_ID',
    api_secret_key='MY_API_SECRET_KEY'
)

nft_address = 'AC6JJcepC9hZzHGVDmx5F3LSGeRhdok1VkcLSZsHoy26'

# --- metadata ---

data = BLOCKCHAIN_API_RESOURCE.get_nft_metadata(
    mint_address=nft_address,
    network=SolanaNetwork.MAINNET_BETA
)

pprint.pprint(data)

# --- owner ---

data = BLOCKCHAIN_API_RESOURCE.get_nft_owner(
    mint_address=nft_address,
    network=SolanaNetwork.MAINNET_BETA
)

pprint.pprint(data)
```